# Why is the recursion depth in the algorithm so large?

Tags: c++

Code for recursively filling in a unidirectional list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class Queue
{
private:
    class Node;

public:
    Queue()
    {
        size = 0;
        head = nullptr;
    }

    Node* push_back(int data, Node* next)
    {
        static int depth; // recursion depth

        if (next == nullptr)
        {
            next = new Node(data);
            if (size == 0)
                head = next;
            size++;
            return next;
        }
        
        depth++; // recursion depth

        next->pNext = push_back(data, next->pNext);
        return next;
    }
        Node* get_head() { return head; }
    int get_size() { return size; }

private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node* pNext;
        int data;

        Node(int data = int(), Node* pNext = nullptr)
        {
            this->data = data;
            this->pNext = pNext;
        }
    };

    int size;
    Node* head;
};
```

Can you explain why the recursion depth when filling the list through a loop is equal to `(n^2 - n) / 2`, instead of `n`?

Because of this, a stack overflow occurs when the number of elements is greater than 3195.

Comment: "_Explain why the recursion depth when filling the list through a loop is equal to (n^2 - n) / 2_": It is not. You are just misusing the static `depth` variable, which you never reset to zero or decrement when returning from recursive calls. "_stack overflow occurs when the number of elements is greater than 3195_": That's expected even with linear recursion depth. You should not use a recursive algorithm for this. Use an iterative one. Also keep a pointer to the end of the list around. Don't repeatedly iterate the list just to add something to the end.

Comment: I understand that recursion is not suitable for this, but I don't understand why there is so much depth. My task consists precisely in a recursive way of filling in the list

Comment: Because you (presumably) call `push_back` multiple times in your program and each time it increments `depth` for each (recursive or not) call. Your `depth` is _not_ saying anything about recursion depth. It just counts the number of calls to `push_back` in the program in total.

Comment: If you maintain a pointer to the *tail*, you could have O(1) and no recursion for `push_back`.

Comment: If you want the actual recursion depth (rather than the sum of all recursion depths of every previous call) you need to reset `depth` somehow (e.g. reset it to zero before returning to any caller other than itself].

Comment: My rule: *the maximum recursion depth for a recursive function shall be **O(log n)***. Having a **O(n)** depth like this implementation is asking for trouble: it will quickly crash with (not so) big `n`. And this type of recursive function can be very easily converted to a loop, that is easier to understand, easier to debug, safer and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because nothing resets `depth` to zero, before each new value gets inserted.

So, when the 2nd value gets pushed into the linked list, `depth` gets incremented for the first time, from 0 to 1. When the 3rd value gets inserted into the linked list, `depth` then gets incremented from 1 to 2, then to 3. And so on.

You end up counting not just the recursion depth of the last insertion operation, but the sum total of all insertion operations.